# When you need to use AsyncIO and ThreadPoolExecutor, do you need to call loop.close() manually?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#running-and-stopping-the-loop), it states:

> Application developers should typically use the high-level asyncio
>   functions, such as asyncio.run(), and should rarely need to reference
>   the loop object or call its methods.
>   **This section is intended mostly for authors of lower-level code, libraries, and frameworks, who need finer control over the event loop behavior.**

When using both `async` and a `threadpoolexecutor`, as show in the example code (from the docs):

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

def blocking_io():
    # File operations (such as logging) can block the
    # event loop: run them in a thread pool.
    with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read(100)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # 2. Run in a custom thread pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, blocking_io)
        print('custom thread pool', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

1. Do I need to call `loop.close()`, or would the `asyncio.run()` close the loop for me?
2. Is using both `asyncio` and `threadpoolexecutor` together, one of those situations where you need *finer control over the event loop*? Can using both, `asyncio` and `threadpoolexecutor` together be done without referencing the `loop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question #1, The [**coroutines and tasks**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) documentation linked in the Event Loop documentation you reference indicates that asyncio.run closes the loop:

> **asyncio.run(coro, *, debug=False)**
>
> Execute the coroutine coro and return the result.
>
> This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of managing the
>   asyncio event loop and finalizing asynchronous generators.
>
> This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is
>   running in the same thread.
>
> If debug is True, the event loop will be run in debug mode.
>
> **This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the
>   end.** It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and
>   should ideally only be called once.

For #2, that use of get_running_loop with ThreadExecutor is a way to run blocking code without blocking the OS thread. In [Developing with asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#developing-with-asyncio), they indicate:

> The loop.run_in_executor() method can be used with a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to execute blocking code in a different OS thread without blocking the OS thread that the event loop runs in.

It is an exception to the general warning they give in the Event documentation around calling the lower-level methods. So the answer to question #2, the answer is yes, it is one of those situations where you need a small amount of finer control in order to execute this recipe that handles blocking code in async scenarios.

Comment: even if I create a loop manually with `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()`, as long as I use `asyncio.run(method_name)` it will close it, correct? That's how I read that bold statement in your answer. The reason I ask is that the docs warn against using `loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()` unless you really have to,  which leads into my second question.

Comment: The example code is not creating the loop manually. asyncio.run creates the loop, `asyncio.get_running_loop()` returns the currently running loop that was created by asyncio.run. asyncio.run then closes the running loop it (ayncio.run) created after it completes.

Comment: That use of get_running_loop with ThreadExecutor is a way to run blocking code without blocking the OS thread. See [https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html). I think it is an exception to the general warning they give in the Event documentation around calling the lower-level methods.